# write down the equation of the line.?

Tags: geometry

Let $x_1 > 0$ and $y_1 > 0$. If the portion of a line intercepted between the
coordinate axes is bisected at the point $(x_1, y_1)$, write down the equation of
the line.

my trial : i was thinking that the equation of line will be $ \frac{x}{x_1}$ + $\frac{y}{y_1} = 1$

Is its correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Let the equation of the straight line $$\dfrac xa+\dfrac yb=1$$

So, intersections with the axes are $(a,0);(0,b)$

What is their midpoint?

Comment: im not getting...

Comment: @Michael, Please share your confusion, We have $$\dfrac{a+0}2=x_1$$

Comment: thanks  a lots @lab bhattacharjee,,,u have great knowlege in geometry,,,as i see many question u have answered the geometry question with beautiful solution......